# Wait for a fixed time before start another method

Tags: c#, wpf, threadpool, dispatcher

I want to have a way to wait for a method to complete in 5 seconds before start another call. It was like it first display a "Hello" then wait for 5 seconds, then display "World" and wait for another 5 seconds to display both messages again. I have created a DispatcherTimer method but it display the both text in a fast manner inside of waiting 5 seconds.

```
    private void AutoAnimationTrigger(Action action, TimeSpan delay)
    {
        timer2 = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer2.Interval = delay;
        timer2.Tag = action;
        timer2.Tick += timer2_Tick;

        timer2.Start();
    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer2 = (DispatcherTimer)sender;
        Action action = (Action)timer2.Tag;

        action.Invoke();

        timer2.Stop();
    }


 if (counter == 0)
                {
                    AutoAnimationTrigger(new Action(delegate { MessageBox.Show("Hello"); }), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000));
                    AutoAnimationTrigger(new Action(delegate { MessageBox.Show("World"); }), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000));

                }
```

What do I miss or did wrong?

**edit___**

```
 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
        {
            //Thread.Sleep(5000);

            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                TranslateX(4);
                TranslateY(-0.5);

            }), DispatcherPriority.Normal);


            //Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            //{
            //    TranslateY(0.5);
            //}), DispatcherPriority.Normal);

        });
```

Then i just simply call the method..

Comment: Can you precise what C# version you are using? While you display messages, should the rest of the application keep running?

Comment: c# 4.0.. I am sorry.. The messagebox is just a way for me to show my codes are functioning, just for testing, actually I want to animate a model when a kinect device does not detect any skeleton..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `AutoAnimationTrigger` twice which overwrites `timer2`, which you declared as a class variable.
The easier solution for multiple **different** actions would be using `Thread.Sleep`:

```
 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
 {
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    MessageBox.Show("World");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);      
    MessageBox.Show("Hello World");  
 });
```

Comment: Hi..I have a doubt again..how can I wait the dispatcher.invoke to completely run and finish and then only start the next dispatcher.invoke? Thread.sleep is not successful for my case..I have edit my code from my original post..Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: What I mean is for example translate to left, because the translation takes some time to complete. After complete left translation, I will want to translate down, then up and right.

Comment: why do you need Dispatcher.Invoke ?

Comment: Because if I call the translateX directly, an exception error will occured - "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it".

Comment: @user1884304 does this exception occur only in debugger?

Comment: yes..the error is invalidoperationexception when I compile and run.

Comment: @user1884304 set Controls.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Thread.Sleep(5000)` between two method calling.

Comment: Why repeat what someone else said 43 minutes ago?